# Unity Network HTC Vive and Oculus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, unity-networking, htc-vive

I want to sync the position of Vive and Oculus 3d models with the Vive/Oculus Controllers position. In the end I want to see the Vive controllers from Oculus and Oculus controllers from Vive.

What i did until now:

If Vive is the server: From Oculus i see the Vive models moving and everything is fine, but from Vive i can't see the Oculus controllers moving.

If Oculus is the server: From Vive i see the Oculus models moving, but form Oculus i can't see the Vive controllers moving.

Implementation:

I have 4 prefabs:

- Vive controller left
- Vive controller right
- Oculus controller left
- Oculus controller right

All have network identity: local player authority and network transform

Next script is on the player:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (IsVive())
    {
        CmdControllerPositionSyncVive();
    }
    else if (IsOculus())
    {
        CmdControllerPositionSyncOculus();
    }
}
```

Here i check if in the Hierarchy Vive SDK is visible or Oculus SDK is visible and sync the position of the visible one.

```
[Command]
public void CmdControllerPositionSyncVive()
{
    if (_leftControllerSource != null && _viveControllerLeft != null)
        _viveControllerLeft.transform.position = _leftControllerSource.transform.position;
    if (_rightControllerSource != null && _viveControllerRight != null)
        _viveControllerLeft.transform.rotation = _leftControllerSource.transform.rotation;


    if (_rightControllerSource != null && _viveControllerRight != null)
        _viveControllerRight.transform.position = _rightControllerSource.transform.position;
    if (_leftControllerSource != null && _viveControllerLeft != null)
        _viveControllerRight.transform.rotation = _rightControllerSource.transform.rotation;

}

[Command]
public void CmdControllerPositionSyncOculus()
{
    if (_leftControllerSource != null && _oculusControllerLeft != null)
        _oculusControllerLeft.transform.position = _leftControllerSource.transform.position;
    if (_rightControllerSource != null && _oculusControllerRight != null)
        _oculusControllerLeft.transform.rotation = _leftControllerSource.transform.rotation;


    if (_rightControllerSource != null && _oculusControllerRight != null)
        _oculusControllerRight.transform.position = _rightControllerSource.transform.position;
    if (_leftControllerSource != null && _oculusControllerLeft != null)
        _oculusControllerRight.transform.rotation = _rightControllerSource.transform.rotation;
}
```

Here i sync the position and rotation of my 3d models with my controllers.

And i instantiate my prefabs like this:

```
    [Command]
void CmdInstantiteOculusAvatar()
{
    var left = (GameObject)Instantiate(OculusLeftControllerPrefab);
    var right = (GameObject)Instantiate(OculusRightControllerPrefab);

    NetworkServer.Spawn(left);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(right);
}

[Command]
void CmdInstantiteViveAvatar()
{
    var left = (GameObject)Instantiate(ViveLeftControllerPrefab);
    var right = (GameObject)Instantiate(ViveRightControllerPrefab);

    NetworkServer.Spawn(left);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(right);
}
```

I'm beginner so if you have some ideas about what's happening here, please help. I think that the server don't sent data to client, but i'm not sure and i don't know how to do it. I've tried with [ClientRpc] but it didn't work.

Comment: You code looks wrong in many different ways... 1) Why aren't you using a NetworkTransform component? It's the easiest way of syncing a transform. 2) You're sending the commands on a reliable channel, that's a bad idea in general for syncing transforms. 3) Your commands are parameter-less, so how are you actually sending the transform to the server?

Comment: you are right. It was wrong. I spawned my 3d models as players. I modified the script and now it's working.